# How do I properly Load a Workflow after Pausing/Persisting it?

Tags: c#, persistence, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

Using this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729667.aspx) as an example for pausing and resuming, one would assume that this would be pretty straight forward. This is how I'm "pausing" the workflow...

```
LastWfGuid = workflow.Id;
workflow.Unload();
```

Pretty simple, it's supposed to persist to the instance store (which I already set prior to these two lines) and I do see entries in the Instance view and the InstancesTable. When I'm ready to resume the workflow I do this...

```
workflow = new WorkflowApplication( myActivity, myWfArgs );
workflow.InstanceStore = wfStore;
workflow.Load(LastWfGuid);
```

At that point I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the exception message being...

```
Workflow inputs cannot be used with Load or LoadRunnableInstance, since they are only provided to new instances.
```

If I can't load a workflow that was previously persisted, how do I resume it again? I tried simply caling `Persist()` in place of `Unload()` and from the outside it looks ok and I receive no exception. But, the workflow continues to run it's course which is not what I'm looking for. I want to pause and then resume my workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the myWfArgs argument when creating the WorkflowApplication used to load the existing workflow instance. So like this:

```
workflow = new WorkflowApplication(myActivity);
workflow.InstanceStore = wfStore;
workflow.Load(LastWfGuid);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would that fix my load issue? Is there a reason why that would prevent a resume?

Comment: This is great because it does what I need it to do. It pauses and resumes on demand. The only issue I have with this approach is how do I pass in my args that I need or are they part of the state when persisted?

Comment: All data passed to the workflow during startup, as well as in variables in scope at the time, is saved and reloaded as part of the workflow state.

Comment: That makes sense, can I still load a workflow after the app has terminated and is executed again? I'm working on that requirement next.

Comment: Yes, the state is save in the SQL Server database using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

Comment: @Maurice, for this specific terminated app case, how would you determine which which state to load? Id is not enough? Imaging its web app and being used by 10 users at same time? So how you will determine which state to load from sql for given user?

Comment: @immirza You need to store the workflow GUID somewhere yourself so that you can correlate the different users to their workflow instance.

Comment: @Maurice, so you saying. in case of 'app' shut-down, it is our job to reload, resume last persisted Id from store and SqlWorkflowInstanceStore won't help. SqlWorkflowInstanceStore helps only in reloading persisted instance when 'app' wasn't shut-down.

Comment: Yes, with new WorkflowApplication() it's all under your control.

Comment: @Maurice, thanks. can you try to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770577/how-do-i-get-last-persisted-workflow-instance-id-to-reload-it