# How do I get last persisted workflow instance Id to reload it?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Lets say I have persisted `self-hosted workflows` (running locally IIS express) that use `WorkflowApplication` programmatically by using the `SqlWorkflowInstanceStore` object model.

```
app.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
{
    return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
};
```

Then, I accidentally / deliberately stopped my web application, restarted my visual studio (local development).

**My questions:**

1. Restarted my application, How would I retrieve last persisted
   application instance from database and load it for later bookmark
   resumption?
2. How would i get ID of last persisted workflow instance Id and reload
   it using Reload method?

Answer (score 0):

In every instance of workflow I've seen, the Workflow Instance IDs are stored in a separate database so that the system can decide, based on criteria stored with the ID, which workflow to restart from the persistence database.

Comment: As per my understanding and investigation, Workflow resume from start when application kicks on after shutdown operation. There is no built in mechanisiam way to handle this. However, if your application isn't shutdown and you persists, goes idle, resume bookmark then it resume the WF from persist point. If you think i am wrong then share an example or reference from MSDN where they said something about shutdown scenario. Thanks